# php preg_match newline

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to I check for the regex `/^</p>\n/` in the string

```
</p>
blahblahblah
```

I can't seem to get a return value of 1 from php's `preg_match`.

EDIT:

My bad for some reason CR on it's own was my newline character.

Comment: So does that mean it's fixed and this question is now closed?

Comment: There should be a (close) button underneath the question.

Comment: There isn't one http://imagebin.org/188222

Comment: I guess its a rep thing, don't worry about closing it.

Answer (score 7):

Use this code to check for `</p>` followed by all kind of **EOL (End of Line)**

```
$text="</p>
blahblahblah";
if (preg_match('~</p>' . PHP_EOL . '~i', $text, $m ))
   var_dump($m);
```

Note the use of PHP constant **PHP_EOL** which will work on all platforms Windows, *nix or Mac.

**Output**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "</p>
"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you escape the / ?

```
/^<\/p>\n/
```

Also consider:

```
@^</p>\n@
```